# Move onchange(this) from HTML to JavaScript, missing parameter but code breaks when I include it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, parameters

I am trying to write a website for an imaginary ice cream shop in order to practice JavaScript.

```js
function hideAAndB() {
  var pickupDiv = document.getElementById("pickupDiv");
  var deliveryDiv = document.getElementById("deliveryDiv");
  pickupDiv.style.display = "none";
  deliveryDiv.style.display = "none";
}

function hidePickup(x) {
  if (x.checked) {
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "inline";
  }
}

function hideDelivery(x) {
  if (x.checked) {
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "inline";
  }
}

function validate() {

}

function init() {
  hideAAndB()
  var delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
  var pickup = document.getElementById("pickup");
  if (pickup.checked) {
    hideDelivery();
  }
  if (delivery.checked) {
    hidePickup();
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Order Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Order page for Sweet Life.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="study">
  <meta name="author" content="Anon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="orderhtml">
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
      <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
    </header>
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="topnav">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">
      <h2>Order</h2>
    </div>
    <!--Form-->
    <form>
      <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
      <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="chooseDiv" onchange=hidePickup(this) value="Delivery"><br>
      <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
      <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="chooseDiv" onchange=hideDelivery(this) value="Pickup"><br>
      <div id="pickupDiv">
        <br/>
        <p>A's text</p>
        <form id="orderPickupForm">
          <label for="fName">First name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" value=""><br>
          <label for="lName">Last name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" value="">
          <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
          <label for="emailAddress">Email address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value=""><br>
          <select name="selectIceCream" id="selectIceCream">
            <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
            <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
            <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
          </select><br>
          <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
          <select name="selectSize" id="selectSize">
            <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
            <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
            <option value="1L">1L</option>
            <option value="2L">2L</option>
          </select><br>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="deliveryDiv">
        <br/>
        <p>B's text</p>
        <form id="orderDeliveryForm">
          <label for="firstN">First name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="firstN" name="firstN" value=""><br>
          <label for="lastN">Last name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="lastN" name="lastN" value="">
          <label for="emailA">Email address:</label>
          <input type="text" id="emailA" name="emailA" value=""><br>
          <p>Select your desired flavour:</p>
          <select name="selectIceCream">
            <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
            <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
            <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
          </select><br>
          <p>How much ice cream would you like?</p>
          <select name="selectSize">
            <option value="250ml">250ml</option>
            <option value="600ml">600ml</option>
            <option value="1L">1L</option>
            <option value="2L">2L</option>
          </select><br>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, there are several things wrong with the script. Most notably there are no parameters in the function calls for the hideDelivery and hidePickup functions. However, whenever I try to include a parameter for each function call that needs one, the functionality of the page stops working. I have tried including variables (in init) pickup and delivery such that init contains the following code:

```
hideAAndB()
var delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
var pickup = document.getElementById("pickup");
if (pickup.checked) {
        hideDelivery(pickup);
    }
    if (delivery.checked) {
        hidePickup(delivery);
    }
```

But this does not seem to work. In addition to this, you might notice that in the HTML there are two function calls - both  use this as a paramater. What would this look like if I were to move these function calls to the JavaScript instead of leaving them in the HTML?

I was expecting it to function without errors when including a parameter in the relevant function calls in init.

Comment: If you want to learn and practise JS then a few hints here. It is not a good practice to write repetitive code and hardcode 2 elements to switch styles. A single function that checks which button was clicked would be more appropriate. Styles in 2023 should not be changed with `style` which applies a max weight inline-style. Rather make use of `classList` and apply styles at the CSS level. Instead of using if/else you could use `toggle`

Comment: First go to https://validator.w3.org/ and find that you cannot have nested forms. If you click [edit] and then scroll down and click "Edit above snippet" you can see the red tags

Answer (score -1):

You're sending `this` as a parameter to both of your functions which will just pass the HTML element to the event handler.
If you want to know which radio button was clicked, pass `event` as the parameter and you will receive an event object in the handler function.

And if you use `event.target.checked` in both your functions, it will return either true or false based on if the radio button is checked or not. You can build further logic based on this